# what does JhiEventManager do?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I Am building an angularJS5 client using **jhipster client** and I encountered '*JhiEventManage*r' in login typescript file.

```
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';
.....
 constructor(
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager,
...
}
...
...
this.eventManager.broadcast({
      name: 'authenticationSuccess',
      content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
});
```

I just want to know what is the purpose of JhiEventManager and how can I make use of it for other functionality? Is there any help or tutorial docs available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JhiEventManager` is a simple service that is part of the ng-jhipster. You can find the source code for this file at https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/service/event-manager.service.ts

I couldn't find any documentation, but the code is really simple to follow along.

The functionality of the service is to serve as a wrapper to event subscription and broadcasting. For this, they have `broadcast` and `subscribe` methods.

In your example, you are broadcasting an event with the name of `authenticationSuccess`. What you can do with this is to simply listen to the changes from another component as follows:

```
//in the same or different component:
this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', () => {
        console.log('authenticationSuccess called');
        //todo: what you want to do when the event is broadcasted.
    }
);
```

This is simply a wrapper for observables. You may wish to use observables directly instead.

Comment: I have the same code almost and I cannot find my event in any other place in the code lets say it is called 'authenticationSuccess'.  What does this mean?